# Missing backup and restore option in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7-backup, windows-7-restore

I don't know exactly what happen, but I'm thinking it has something to do with Windows 7 upgrade: 2 weeks ago I upgraded to SP1 and pretty sure this is when it happens to "broke" my backup and restore option.

I have a backup schedule added for every week, and I receive the notification to solve 2 PC issues, but when I press on the Backup button nothing happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had similar problem after upgrading to SP1 - this helped me: [how-to-fix-missing-backup-and-restore.html](http://answers-tips.blogspot.com/2011/03/how-to-fix-missing-backup-and-restore.html)

Comment: That was quick :) I'll try it and let you know.

Comment: Looks like I cannot vote you up. I have to wait another 3 minutes to accept your answer... Maybe after that I can upvote :)

Comment: Don't worry, glad you could solve your problem.